# How to save grabbed image to user-input directory in Python

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, export

I have worked at this code:

```
def getnsave(event):
    widget=event.widget
    x=root.winfo_rootx()+widget.winfo_x()
    y=root.winfo_rooty()+widget.winfo_y()
    x1=x+widget.winfo_width()
    y1=y+widget.winfo_height()
    formats=[('Obrázky (.png)','*.png'),('Obrázky (.jpg)','*.jpg')]
    img=ImageGrab.grab().crop((x,y,x1,y1))
    f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes=(("Portable Network Graphics (*.png)", "*.png"),("All Files (*.*)", "*.*")),mode='w',defaultextension='.png')
    if f is None:
        return
    f.write(img)
    f.close()
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Image
```

Please, help me. I understand, that after I select the directory, I need to command WHAT to save. Do You know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save a PIL image to a file, you have to use the [`Image.save`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) method. Two things are important to make this work correctly:

1. The file must be opened in binary mode.

   This means you have to change change the `w` file mode in

   ```
   filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes=(("Portable Network Graphics (*.png)", "*.png"),
                                       ("All Files (*.*)", "*.*")),
                            mode='w',
                            defaultextension='.png')
   ```

   to `wb` like so:

   ```
   filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes=(("Portable Network Graphics (*.png)", "*.png"),
                                       ("All Files (*.*)", "*.*")),
                            mode='wb',
                            defaultextension='.png')
   ```
2. PIL needs to know in which format you want to save the image. You can extract the format from the file extension like so:

   ```
   filename = f.name
   extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
   ```

Putting all of this together:

```
f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes=(("Portable Network Graphics (*.png)", "*.png"),
                                        ("All Files (*.*)", "*.*")),
                             mode='wb',
                             defaultextension='.png')
if f is None:
    return

filename = f.name
extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]

img.save(f, extension)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the `ImageGrab` module from `PIL` even if you do not show the `import` command in your code snippet. If `PIL` is active, you can write your image with:

```
img.save(filename,'PNG')
```

Note that `filedialog.asksaveasfile` returns the filename, not a file object. So you can use it directly in the previous command

Comment: Thanks, guys. It helped a lot